# Set a ng-class to true or false

Tags: angularjs

I have a Icon element that I want to switch class depending on something else,

```
%i.fa.fa-bell{"ng-class" => "newActivities"}
```

I have a if/else statement in my controller,

```
var activities = $scope.activities

var init = function(){
  var hasValue = activities.some(function(obj) { return obj.viewed == "uncheck" });
  console.log (hasValue)

  if (hasValue == true){
    checked = true ;
    $scope.newActivities = 'newActivities';
  }
}

$scope.viewActivities = function (){
  angular.forEach(activities, function (activitie) {
    viewActivities.update({
      viewed: `check`,
      id:      activitie.id
    }).then(init);
  });
  $scope.newActivities = '';
}
```

What happens now is that when the if value is true, the `$scope.newActivities` adds the `newActities` to the ng-class element. But I can't figure out how to remove the class when the statement isn't true.

Answer (score 5):

Well, all you need to do is to clean up your class variable like so:

```
$scope.newActivities = '';
```

It will make `ng-class` re-render the `class` attribute of the element.

Comment: I've updated the code a little but, but your suggestion doesn't seem to work for me. When the `init` function runs, I do get the `false` message in my browsers log. But the ng-class remains the same untill I refresh.

Comment: Yeap! That's because you're init function is running only once. Anyway, if when you refresh, the behavior is applied, then this technique does works don't you?

Comment: Hm. I call the `init` function after a call my `viewActivities` function. This returns a `false` (so it runs the init) but doesn't remove the ng-class. I fixed it by placing the `$scope.newActivities = '';` inside that `viewActivities` function though.

Comment: Got It! I think because your init function is running asynchronous, this commonly causes `$scope` to not be applied. Anyway to force a scope apply you use `$scope.$apply()` or one of his variations depending on the circumstances.

Comment: Couldn't see this without the rest of code. Anyway, your problem was solved. Regards :)

Comment: YOu need a standing ovation i must say instead of make it false make it empty